# PWA in Firefox on android not updating (Chrome works fine)

Tags: android, firefox, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA, that's working absolutely fine in Chrome and Firefox on Android.

However when I update any files, only the chrome PWA seems to realize there's any updates (which it will install when I close the app and open it again).

I've tried updating the service worker, renaming the cache, etc. but nothing seems to help (okay, I tried uninstalling Firefox and re-installing it, that worked).

I have spent ages Googling, but can't seem to find anyone with the same problem, so I feel like I must be missing something obvious here, and I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

The PWA can be found here:
https://web.podfriend.com/

And the service worker here:
https://web.podfriend.com/serviceworker.js

Answer (score 0):

For whoever ends up in the same problem, I think I finally solved this.

It turns out that there was some kind of Javascript error in regards to an audio component. This Javascript error was for some reason or the other only triggered on a update (and was only existing in Firefox).

I'm still not exactly sure of the specifics, but everything worked after cleaning that up.